# Convert from scala.collection.Seq<String> to java.util.List<String> in Java code

Tags: java, scala, type-conversion, scala-java-interop

I'm calling a Scala method, from Java. And I need to make the conversion from Seq to List.

I can't modified the signature of the Scala method, so I can't used the `asJavaCollection` method from `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`

Any ideas of how can I achieve this?

Using Scala 2.9.3

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You're on the right track using `JavaConversions`, but the method you need for this particular conversion is `seqAsJavaList`:

```
java.util.List<String> convert(scala.collection.Seq<String> seq) {
    return scala.collection.JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(seq);
}
```

**Update**: `JavaConversions` is deprecated, but the same function can be found in [`JavaConverters`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html).

```
java.util.List<String> convert(scala.collection.Seq<String> seq) {
    return scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(seq);
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to **import scala.collection.JavaConversions;** in eclipse. its showing Error here

Comment: Not sure if this is new or not but I had to do `seqAsJavaList(seq).asJava` to get the actual `List<E>`

Comment: Just added an anonymous edit to this point to use the new JavaConverters class (since 2.8.1). Hopefully will be approved.

Comment: @Decoded: Thanks for the improvement :) I didn't accept the edit as-is because I wanted the answer to still make sense in the context of the question, but I added an amendment that uses `JavaConverters`.

Comment: Thanks! Love to be on the cutting edge :D

Answer (score 8):

Since Scala 2.9, you shouldn't use implicits from `JavaConversions` since they are deprecated and will soon be removed. Instead, to convert `Seq` into java `List` use `convert` package like this (although it doesn't look very nice):

```
import scala.collection.convert.WrapAsJava$;

public class Test {
    java.util.List<String> convert(scala.collection.Seq<String> seq) {
        return WrapAsJava$.MODULE$.seqAsJavaList(seq);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a good idea for scala to provide a more java-friendly set of frontend methods for these kinds of conversions.

Answer (score 8):

Since 2.12 this is the recommended way:

```
public static <T> java.util.List<T> convert(scala.collection.Seq<T> seq) {
    return scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(seq);
}
```

All other methods a `@deprecated("use JavaConverters or consider ToJavaImplicits", since="2.12.0")`

Answer (score 0):

(In case you want to do this conversion in Scala code)

You can use JavaConverters to make this really easy.

```
import collection.JavaConverters._
val s: Seq[String] = ...
val list: java.util.List<String> = s.asJava
```

Comment: The question asks for the conversion in Java code, not Scala code.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I knew I found it strange that no one had suggested this solution yet - makes sense now.