# Type mismatch Passing an Array in Scala JUnit test to Java method

Tags: java, arrays, scala, junit, scala-collections

I am Scala newbie

I have a java method like this below

```
public void myMethod (Collection<String> param) throws MyException {
    // process param
}
```

I want to test this method using a Scala Junit test

```
@Test
def myMethodTest() {
    try {
        ....myMethod(Seq("myString"))
    } catch {
        case e : MyException => throw new AssertionError ("Failed myMethod : " + e.getMessage)
    }
}
```

But it is giving me a Type mismatch error. How can I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737631/convert-from-scala-collection-seqstring-to-java-util-liststring-in-java-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Seq` is not a Java `Collection`. You should use `JavaConverters` implicits to convert them:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

myMethod(Seq("myString").asJava)
```

Or you can use Java collections directly, for example, via `Arrays.asList()`:

```
import java.util.Arrays

myMethod(Arrays.asList("myString"))
```