# Converting Scala seq<string> to Java List<string>

Tags: java, scala

I'm working in Java. I need to convert a `Seq<String>` returned from a Scala method in Apache Kafka to a Java `List<String>` for processing.

I've found a method that can do the trick, `seqAsJavaList`, in the scala.collection.convert.WrapAsJava class.

https://www.garysieling.com/scaladoc/scala.collection.convert.wrapasjava/2016/02/15/scala__collection_convert_WrapAsJava.html

I've also found a StackOverflow query that's been helpful.

[Convert from scala.collection.Seq<String> to java.util.List<String> in Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737631/convert-from-scala-collection-seqstring-to-java-util-liststring-in-java-code/27110969#27110969)

However, when I try the following code -

```
public static void listTopics ()
{
    ZkClient zkClient = connectToZookeeper();
    ZkUtils zkUtils = zookeeperUtility(zkClient);

    List<String> brokerTopics = WrapAsJava.seqAsJavaList(zkUtils.getAllTopics());

    zkClient.close();
}
```

I get the compiler error that non-static method seqAsJavaList cannot be referenced from a static context.

I can't instantiate WrapAsJava, so I have no idea how I could create a non-static context here.

The StackOverflow query had an answer with this code snippet.

```
import scala.collection.convert.WrapAsJava;

public class Test {
java.util.List<String> convert(scala.collection.Seq<String> seq) {
    return WrapAsJava.seqAsJavaList(seq);
}
}
```

Sadly, it raises the same error. How can I fix this? Thank you!

(Here is the method zkUtils.getAllTopics())

```
  def getAllTopics(zkClient: ZkClient): Seq[String] = {
val topics = ZkUtils.getChildrenParentMayNotExist(zkClient, BrokerTopicsPath)
if(topics == null)
  Seq.empty[String]
else
  topics
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scala.collection.JavaConversions`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;
import scala.collection.immutable.Seq;

Seq<String> strings = ... //
List<String> javaList = JavaConversions.seqAsJavaList(strings);
```