# Convert Scala Seq to Java List

Tags: java, scala

I am working in Java. I am calling a scala function which returns a Seq[String]. To convert it to java's List, I tried using scala.collection.JavaConverters's asJava. But this does not seem to work.

Answers on similar questions have suggested either using JavaConversions or WrapAsJava, both of which are deprecated.

Similar Question - [Converting Scala seq<string> to Java List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894807/converting-scala-seqstring-to-java-liststring)

```
//someScalaFunc returns a Seq[String]
List<String> listA = someScalaFunc();
```

Answer (score 11):

Since `JavaConversions` is **deprecated**, You can use  `JavaConverters` for this:

```
List<String> listA = scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList(someScalaFunc())
```

Comment: This worked fine, but I tried to import it statically, but someScalaFunc() is a generic function. Is there a way to import it in a static fashion, and avoid using class name with the function call?

Comment: import `import static scala.collection.JavaConverters.seqAsJavaList` and use `seqAsJavaList(someScalaFunc())`, Isn't it enough?

Comment: No, it gives this error -
seqAsJavaList (Seq<A>) in javaconverters cannot be applied to Seq<java.lang.String>

And I checked that generic functions cannot be imported in a static way, either full class name has to be used or their return value should be stored in an intermediate variable. In this case intermediate variable cannot be used to store the scala Seq.

Comment: @piyushaggarwal try `JavaConverters.<String>seqAsJavaList(someScalaFunc())`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Java to Scala implicit converter by importing the following:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val scalaList = List("A", "B", "c")

scalaList.asJava
```