# How do I can convert Scala for loop into Java

Tags: java, scala, geojson, kml, kmz

Here are some lines of code that need to convert into Java.

```
val geojsonSeq = for (kml <- kmlSeq) yield kmlConverter.toGeoJson(kml)
```

I tried to convert using for each loop in java using lamda operator but not able to get it.

```
kmlSeq.foreach((Function1<Option<Kml>, U>) (f) -> {
            
        });
```

Every time I am getting compile-time error like:
"The method foreach(Function1<Option,U>) is ambiguous for the type Seq<Option>"

Apart from this if I'm going to use normally for each loop in java like :

```
for(Option<Kml> kml : kmlSeq)
        {
            
        }
```

In that case kmlSeq is throwing error like :
"Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"
But in scala the kmlSeq looping into Option object.

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107772/convert-scala-seq-to-java-list

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of two ways (Assuming return type of toGeoJson is String)

```java
List<String> result = kmlSeq
  .stream()
  .flatMap(kmlOpt -> 
    kmlOpt.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
  )
  .map(kml -> kmlConverter.toGeoJson(kml))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```java
List<String> result = kmlSeq
  .stream()
  .flatMap(kmlOpt -> 
    kmlOpt.map(kml ->
      Stream.of(kmlConverter.toGeoJson(kml))
    ).orElseGet(Stream::empty)
  )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To print, do this

```java
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Hi Praphull thanks for providing the solution but I am getting an error on the .stream() method as "The method stream() is undefined for the type Seq<Option<Kml>>", Is there any alternatives for it.